# Who coined the term: "Directed Graph"?

Tags: mathematicians, terminology, graph-theory

I found that the term "***Digraph***" was coined in 1955 by Frank Harary in ["The number of linear, directed, rooted, and connected graphs"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1993073?seq=1), and that it was a term actually suggested by George Pólya as Harary later tells in 1989 in ["The Pólya Picture Album—Encounters of a Mathematician"](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1989.11972278?journalCode=uamm20)

Now, the problem is that in some places like in this one: [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics (D)](https://jeff560.tripod.com/d.html) it is said that the term "***Directed Graph***" was also introduced in that same paper

> DIGRAPH was used in 1955 by F. Harary in Transactions of the American Mathematical Society. The term directed graph also occurs there [OED].

But if you check older texts like in the first textbook about graph theory: ["Theorie der endlichen und unendlichen Graphen"](http://www.gbv.de/dms/ilmenau/toc/160367581.PDF) by Dénes Kőnig published in 1936, the Chapter 7 is called: "Basisprobleme für ***Gerichtete Graphen***" which is translated as: "Basis Problems for ***Directed Graphs***"

So, when did the term "***Directed Graph***" actually appear?